# Kotlin: Idiomatic & Declarative way to find count of a loop without mutation

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, declarative

How to count no.of times a loop has run with a condition, for example:

```
var count = 0
while (stk.isNotEmpty()) {
  stack.pop()
  count++
}
```

But this involves a temporary counter and mutation. Is there a better idiomatic and declarative way without using any temp variable and mutation. I could come-up with something like this, but it does feel hacky:

```
val count = stk.takeWhile { stk.isNotEmpty() }.also { stk.pop() }.count()
```

Comment: In this particular case you could use `stk.size` or `stk.count()` since you pop any element from the stack regardless. pls show a use-case where this is not the case.

Comment: This is just a simple sample code, to demo my need of find loop count with a condition, nothing specific to stack

Comment: yes, but you need something to call `takeWhile` on... in this case you have a stack. What what you have to call higher-order functions on in another case? What I want to say is that your need strongly depends on the particular use-case.

Comment: Like I said, pls show another example. The answer most likely is: No, there is no better way of doing it, than using a while loop and a counter variable.

Comment: I am looking for if there is a construct that is similar to this: 
`val count = repeatWhile(stk.isNotEmpty()) { stk.pop() }.count()`
This is agnostic of the condition inside `repeatWhile()`

Comment: see my answer pls

Comment: If you want to avoid intermediate variables and reassignments you must create a new scope for each iteration. Instead of reassigning an intermediate value to a temporary variable you can pass it to a function by calling it. Since you don't know the number of function calls upfront you need (tail) recursion. You can abstract from recursion by applying a fold/reduce.

Comment: @bob would you mind explaining with some example code.

Comment: To avoid mutations (stack) you can create a new stack for every iteration. Since this is quite inefficient you should use a persistent stack based on a persistent data structure. I don't know if there is an appropriate library in Kotlin though.

Comment: @GopalSAkshintala does the answer suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kotlin standard library does not offer what you are looking for, but you could create something you are searching for own your own:

```
fun repeatWhile(condition: () -> Boolean, action: () -> Unit): Int {
    var count = 0
    while (condition()) {
        action()
        count++
    }
    return count
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val stack = Stack<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)

val count = repeatWhile({ stack.isNotEmpty() }) {
    stack.pop()
}

println(count) // 3
```

Personally, I don't think this a better than exposing the while-loop and the counter variable to the call-site, like you did in your question.